# Can the verizon iPad update to ios 4.3?

Tags: ios, ipad

I had an email from Apple the other day saying

"Our records indicate that one of your apps requires iOS 4.3 or later.
Currently, iPhone users on the Verizon network are not able to upgrade
to iOS 4.3 and are unable to find any apps requiring iOS 4.3 or later
on the App Store. Unless your app is using iOS 4.3 functionality, such
as AirPlay, we recommend changing the iOS Deployment Target build
setting of your app to an earlier version of iOS."

I don't have any iPhone apps on my account that require 4.3 , I do however have an iPad app on the store that requires 4.3 . Could this just be a mistake? Can people who own a Verizon iPad download my 4.3 app?

Answer (score 2):

iPad 1 from Verizon was a normal iPad with a Verizon hotspot, and they can update to 4.3. [According to Apples website](http://www.apple.com/ios/), iPad 2 from Verizon (which now has a CDMA chip inside) can also update to 4.3.

Verizon iPhones can not update to 4.3, and that may be what this is about. Verizon iPhones are still 4.2, and so therefore if you are targeting 4.3 - those verizon iPhone users can't use your application. Their email states that this is just Verizon iPhone users.

Comment: You are correct about the Verizon iPad 1, but the Verizon iPad 2 has its own built-in CDMA 3G system.

Comment: @CajunLuke - I cant believe how I forgot about that, updating now.